# Cassandra upsert not working

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, upsert, cqlsh

My cqlsh version is 3.3.1, and I am using datastax.cassandra java driver for connecting. Following is my Cassandra schema.

```
url text PRIMARY KEY,
ae_rank int,
age int,
brands list<text>,
cities list<text>,
content text,
countries list<text>,
created timestamp,
customer_id text,
datasource list<text>,
diseases list<frozen<disease>>,
drugs list<text>,
gender int,
host text,
lang text,
meddracoding list<text>,
molecules list<text>,
owners list<text>,
page_rank int,
pj_terms list<frozen<pj_term>>,
projects list<text>,
quintilesims_id int,
reviewed int,
sentiment int,
social_tags list<text>,
switchovers list<frozen<switchover>>,
taxonomies list<frozen<taxonomy>>,
therapy_areas list<text>,
title text,
total_count bigint,
ts timestamp,
type text,
updated timestamp,
viralities map<text, bigint>
```

When there's an update (or insert) statement issue with same primary key value, the relevant row values does not get updated. Here we use an URL as primary key value (ex. http://example.com/example/1234test)

Is this an issue with the versions of Cassandra or the java driver?

Please help get this resolved.

Comment: Show your update/insert statement

Comment: A bit more information is needed - what is your cluster size? Replication factor? Which consistency levels are used? What are the acutal statements used?

Comment: Cluster size : 2, Rep factor :2 , The statement is "INSERT INTO schema.table (url,k,....) values('http://example.com/example/1234test',...)". All other settings were default.

Comment: What version of cassandra are you running and what version of the driver are you using? Are there any errors in system.log after doing the insert? How are you determining that the update hasn't been successful? It would still be helpful if you put the insert you are doing on your question.